# How do I set folder to writable on Azure for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an MVC application deployed to Azure from Team Services. My application needs write permissions to my content directory to save image files.

I looked in Azure portal and didn't find any settings for this.
I also googled and still had no luck.

Does anyone know how to set folder permissions to writable in Azure?

Comment: Ideally, you do not want to save images in directory. Instead you want to use Blob Stroage.

Comment: Agree with @Win, the space on a virtual machine is limited and you should not write to an application root folder. That is what Azure storage is for.